# Whats equivalent for "performance machines" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

I'm trying to figure the equivalent for performance machine/device/system in German.

So far I have got the followings but I am not sure if it is correct or not:

- > Leistungssyteme
- > Leistungsmachine
- > Leistungsrechner
- > Hochleistungsrechner

Which one sounds correct and perfect in a German way?

Comment: A qualified answer would need information about the area of technology you are dealing with.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann involved more in IoT developements

Answer (score 4):

It has to be **Hochleistungs-**, because *Leistung* simply means *power* or *performance* and there's a value missing. I wonder if the *high* is really skipped often in English either.

> das Hochleistungssystem  — high performance system
>
> die Hochleistungsma**s**chine — high performance machine
>
> der Hochleistungsrechner — supercomputer

Mind the **s** in the German *die Maschine*.

Comment: this word comes at the end of the name which i am using for my new venture... so i think in terms of business [performance](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/performance.html) is right i guess... also the abbreviation of my venture ends up like this **ZFL**, but as you suggested Hochleistungs the abbr. would be **ZFH** which doesn't blend well.

Comment: It sounds silly either way. German in general pivots around the last item (applies to lists, compounds, clauses etc.) and your ZFLS or ZFHS has the L/H in the middle. It's **unimportant** then.